# Uncorrect dlarray dimensions and labels when testing a custom reshape deep learning layer

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I am developing a neural network using Matlab R2023b and I need to perform some matrix operations within a layer that should also perform a reshape of the input passing from a 86(S)x2025(C)x1(B) to 9(S)x9(S)x5(C)x1(B),the number of elements does not match because of the matrix operations...

So, I wrote down the layer and the following is the minimum code that generates the error:

```
classdef testLayer < nnet.layer.Layer ...
                        & nnet.layer.Formattable  
    
    properties
        dimension
        nClass
    end
  
    methods
        function layer = testLayer(dimension, nClass, args)
            arguments 
                dimension
                nClass
                args.Name = "";
            end

            layer.Name = args.Name; 
            layer.dimension = dimension;
            layer.nClass = nClass;
        end

        function Z = predict(layer,X)
            inputSize = size(X);
            if length(inputSize) < 3
                inputSize = [inputSize, 1];
            end
                        
            Z = zeros([layer.dimension(1),layer.dimension(2),layer.nClass,inputSize(end)]);

            %operations using X that is split in two matrices to generate Z...

            Z = dlarray(single(Z),'SSCB');
        end

        function dLdX = backward(layer,X,~,dLdZ,~)        
            inputSize = size(X);

            dLdX1 = zeros([layer.dimension(1)*layer.dimension(2),inputSize(2)]);
            dLdX2 = zeros([layer.nClass,inputSize(2)]);
            
            %operations using X, that is split in two matrices, and dLdZ to compute dLdX1 and dLdX2...

            dLdX = cat(1,dLdX1, dLdX2);
            dLdX = dlarray(single(dLdX),'SCB');
        end

    end
end
```

I have tested it using the checkLayer() Matlab function in this way:

```
layer = testLayer([9 9], 5);
layout = networkDataLayout([86 2025 1],"SCB");
checkLayer(layer,layout)
```

and the result is this one:

```
..... ......
================================================================================
Error occurred in nnet.checklayer.TestLayerWithBackward/gradientsAreNumericallyCorrect and it did not run to completion.
    ---------
    Error ID:
    ---------
    'deep:dlarray:MoreDimsThanLabels'
    --------------
    Error Details:
    --------------
    Error using dlarray
    Number of dimension labels in data format must be greater than or equal to the number of dimensions of the
    data
    array.
    
    Error in nnet.checklayer.IntermediateLayerTestCase/generateData (line 353)
                        data = dlarray(data, test.Format{i});
    
    Error in nnet.checklayer.TestLayerWithBackward/gradientsAreNumericallyCorrect (line 268)
                dLdZ = test.generateData( iAllSizes(Z), 'double' );
================================================================================
.
Done nnet.checklayer.TestLayerWithBackward
__________

Failure Summary:

     Name                                                                                     Failed  Incomplete  Reason(s)
    ========================================================================================================================
     nnet.checklayer.TestLayerWithBackward/backwardDoesNotError(Observations=multiple)          X         X       Errored.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     nnet.checklayer.TestLayerWithBackward/backwardIsConsistentInSize(Observations=multiple)    X         X       Errored.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     nnet.checklayer.TestLayerWithBackward/gradientsAreNumericallyCorrect                       X         X       Errored.
```

but I don't understand what I am doing wrong because the format of the array in output of the backward matches the input and the same does the output of the predict function with respect to the expected output of the layer.

Moreover when tested on a system that has a GPU, I get also the following error:

```
. .......
================================================================================
Verification failed in nnet.checklayer.TestLayerWithBackward/backwardIsConsistentInType(Precision=double,Device=gpu).
    ----------------
    Test Diagnostic:
    ----------------
    Incorrect type of 'dLdX' for 'backward'.
    ---------------------
    Framework Diagnostic:
    ---------------------
    Actual Underlying Type:
        single
    Expected Underlying Type:
        double
```

Obviously, I tried to switch from single to double but then it asks for the single type...

Comment: I solved the last error...I should have add `'like', X` when initializing the arrays using the zeros function. But I still have problems on the initial tests...